# redirect servlet status to modal html page

Tags: javascript, servlets

I have an HTML page containig a form filling, the submit will trigger the servlet to create a new record in the database.

once the servlet has done the job, I would like to redirect on the same HTML page issuing the form by opening a popup modal indicating the status of the command (failed, success).

I Googled my problem and found some solutions with sendRedirect and modal_popup but I'm not able to get something working properly....

here is the modal I would like to call from my servlet thanks to `response.sendRedirect`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pop_up_modal() {
$( "#modal_popup" ).dialog({
  height: 140,
  modal: true,
  title: "The title of your modal popup",
  open: function(){
    $( "#modal_popup" ).append("The text that you want in the modal.");
  }
});
```

};

and when the end user click on the ok button of the modal, I would like to open another HTML page showing all the records...

I tried to call the Javascript method by using

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">pop_up_modal();</script>");
    out.close();
```

but I have the following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: pop_up_modal is not defined`

any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I updated my post with some more code....

Comment: ok, I understood (sorry for my lack of knowledge....), my html page let's say add.html will call my Servlet SaveServlet, when my servlet finish its processing, I would need to redirect to the same HTML page but by calling a javascript popup

Comment: Happy Learning :-)